# Proving the set of all cluster points is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

if $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can I prove that "the set of all cluster points of A is closed" using the following:

- A closed subset is a subset that contains all its limit points.
- Every cluster point is a limit point (Not vice versa though).
- A has all cluster points means that it includes all its limits point and hence
  A is closed.

Is this an enough proof ?

Comment: What is your definition of a cluster point and a limit point?

Comment: A point a∈⟨X,d⟩ is a cluster point of a sequence (xn) if
∀ϵ>0,∀n∈N,∃p>n⟹d(xp,a)<ϵ

Comment: A number p is said to be a limit point of a set of reals, S, if every neigbourhood of p has at least one element of the set S different from p

Comment: So you have shown that every point in the set of cluster points is a limit point. How do you prove that there are no points outside of the set which are limit points?

Comment: @rubikscube09 A REALLY important question, since many mathematicians take limit and cluster points as identical, but some do not.I don't think we can go forward answering this unless the OP does.

Comment: @rubikscube09 good point. I don't know.

Comment: Your proof seems to be missed a step. Where does the sequence {$\mathbb(a_n}} appear in the proof? Do you assume the sequence defined in A and take the face every cluster point of the sequence is also a limit point of A? Are the cluster points of this sequence the only limit points of A?  That seems problematic to me,although I'm a little rusty here.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Sorry, didn't see you beat me to the obvious question.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Not a problem

Comment: sorry not A that has to be closed. Only the subset of the cluster points of A has to be closed

Comment: What is the definition "$p$ is a cluster point of $A$", where $A$ is a **set**, not a sequence?

Comment: @Jeff Ah, there you go, knew something looked wrong with your problem statement!

Comment: Can I claim that the set of all cluster points of A is closed as the cluster points are limit points so this subset will not have any limit point out of the set, so as all the limit points are included it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

hint. Let $C$ be the set of cluster points of $A$. First you need to state what you need to prove. You need to prove that if $c$ is a limit point of $C$, then $c\in C$. In other words, you need to prove that if $c$ is a limit point of $C$ then $c$ is a cluster points of $A$. Since you work with subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, it is enough to work with sequences. You may pick a sequence $c_n,$ $n\ge1,$ of points of $C$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=c.$ For each $n$ you may pick a sequence of points $a_{n,m}$, $m\ge1$, in $A$, such that $\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{n,m}=c_n.$ Now, you could either consider an arbitrary neighborhood $O$ of $c$ and show that $O$ necessarily intersects $A$, or, alternatively, you could pick suitable $m(n)$ for each $n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,m(n)}=c.$

> Say, for each $n$ pick $m(n)$ big enough such that the distance from $a_{n,m(n)}$ to $c_n$ is less than $\frac1n.$ Then show that necessarily $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,m(n)}=c.$ (If you are not sure if my hint is complete, you may wish to consider more cases, depending of the distinction between cluster points and limit points, and keep track which points may belong to which set. But the main case would be similar to the hint I sketched here.)